# Removing Apps from SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, site-template, app

When you create a template it makes it available within the Apps section within Site Contents.  Now, I want it deleted.  I deleted the template but it is still available in the "Apps You Can Add" section in the Add App page.

How can I delete the app so it's not available to anyone?

Note:  I went to the License section and this app does not appear in the section.

Comment: Was it a list template?

Comment: @KayleeChatham Yes, its a list template.

Comment: Did you delete your list template from here? > http://YOURSITE/_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: @eVT Yes, I did delete from the list catalogs page.  However, it still appears within "Apps You Can Add" section.

Comment: I have same problem. Could anyone help?